# Delete link-only answers to "plz send teh linkz" questions?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, recommendation-questions

Occasionally I'll see a question along the lines of

> Plz recommend a tutorial about how to parse HTML with regex?

And the answers are like

> Try [this](http://www.howtoparsehtmlwithregex.com/tutorial) great tutorial!

> You should look at [How To Parse HTML with Regex](http://www.howtoparsehtml.com/regex).

**Should these answers be deleted?** On one hand, they are link-only answers, but on the other hand, they do answer the question.

The question should obviously be closed if it hasn't already.

Comment: Delete with extreme prejudice... Both the question and the answers.

Comment: The question itself is the problem. Close and delete it and the answers take care of themselves.

Comment: You need a bigger hat to delete this crap.

Comment: While the guys have answered your question already, I'd suggest that this is already well covered: [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as “not an answer”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505/146015), [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183603/146015), [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/146015)

Comment: Those questions fall under "recommend an off-site resource", so flag to close and all the answers will go down with the ship.

Comment: Kill it with Fire

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why waste your time and effort deleting crappy answers? Spend your time closing and deleting the question and the answers will go with it.

Honestly, I decline silly VLQ and NAA flags on answers like this, because deleting the answer is not helpful. Deleting the question *is helpful*. If you see a particularly atrocious question with a lot of crappy link answers, just cast one flag on the question requesting it be nuked and move on. Don't waste your flags and delete votes on the rest of the content.

Comment: But nobody ever deletes questions. Sure, they may be closed and -1'd but the answers are always upvoted and accepted. There aren't enough 10kers running around to delete the sheer amount of crap even if they *were* running around. And what am I supposed to do?

Comment: *"If you see a particularly atrocious question with a lot of crappy link answers, just cast one flag on the question requesting it be nuked and move on."*

Comment: "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention", "The community can handle it itself"

Comment: @bjb568 If you're referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967412/add-and-remove-class-to-span-using-jquery), I don't see how it's relevant here at all. It does not contain "crappy link-only answers" - in fact, one of them has quite a bit of detail.

Comment: Not just specific cases. I don't recall *ever* seeing a question deleted by a mod by request. Chat users don't say "hey this should be deleted, let's get a mod to do it", it's always "del-vote-pls" (or just cv-pls since del/down-vote is implied (since at least half of questions deserve it all)) which never goes thru (not enough 10kers). Most people wait for Community to do things, but the whores get there first.

Comment: This is a rather specific scenario where an entire question and most if not all its answers are useless. We do delete these types of questions that are just rotting garbage; I've done it many times myself and I've had several of my own flags to nuke truly terrible questions acted upon. But we're also talking about **completely useless crap** - if there's any sign of something useful in the question or its answers, we usually opt to leave it for the community.

Comment: Why? If it's a typo, blatantly off-topic, recommendation, or GIVE ME TEH CODEZ, leaving it on the site is actively harmful.

Comment: I agree with @bjb568. Cleaning up crap stuff ASAP is useful for the site. If we can clean up more crap later, all the better, but we should not leave crap in place which we can already deal with, right now, no matter what happens later.

Comment: I'm seeing comments suggesting "just delete" and "not enough 10Kers". Is there something about having 10K (or soon to have 100K) that gets you a deletion-hammer? I just got my duplicate-close-hammer and have wielded it a few times.

Comment: @BondedDusr No. The only people who can insta-delete a question or answer are moderators, and the OP (under certain circumstances). 10k users just have the ability to vote to delete, and it takes at least three of them.

Comment: What you should do in practice: Depending on your rep, either flag or close vote the question, reason off-topic because asking to recommend an off-site resource.

Answer (score 5):

> Should these answers be deleted?

Yes, **please**.

[image]

I agree with @apaul34208 and @bjb568 in the comments: Do not leave those OPs with encouragement providing the message that what they are doing is fine and they will eventually get answers. I would even go further and *downvote* those before flagging them to make the process smoother and fair.

Cleaning up the partially motivating factor for those questions *should be done ASAP IMHO* and I think it is useful for the site. If we can clean up further bad content later, all the better, but we should not leave needless posts in place which we can already deal with, right now, no matter what happens later.

Just to make it clear: I agree about that with animuson's answer that the questions should be closed and deleted, too, but it is a less smooth process which has to wait a bit. Sometimes it gets stuck, sometimes it does not, so we need to do our best to clean up as much bad content as possible, not backing one with another potential that may be deleted (or not).

One typical example is when the question actually turns out to be something meaningful: the answer left is clear candidate for closure and it just becomes noise. Even if that does not happen, it is still a link-only or otherwise bad answer, so I cannot possibly imagine a scenario when that answer would be useful, but on the contrary: the risk is there to leave it around if it does not get deleted ASAP.